# No handlers could be found for logger "apscheduler.scheduler"

Tags: python, scheduler

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
import os
class ListHref():
    def __init__(self):
       print 'In ListHref Class!'
       self.name_hrefs = {}
       self.name_img = {}
       self.path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
       print 'Out ListHref Class'
    def other_function():...

def job(): #function named job
    print 'In job!'
    book_href = ListHref()
    print 'book_href created!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sched = Scheduler()
    #job() #it's ok if job() called only
    sched.daemonic = False #non daemon thread 
    sched.add_interval_job(job,minutes=0.1)
    sched.start()
```

**Problem:**
If call job() only instead of sched,it's ok
So I am confused that why the **init**(self) cannot called completely?
and what's wrong with 'No handerls could be found for logger "apscheduler.scheduler"'?
**Above python code result:**

In job()

In ListHref Class!

No handerls could be found for logger "apscheduler.scheduler"

In job()

In ListHref Class!

In job()

In ListHref Class!

...(so on)

Comment: Try initializing the [logging](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module. Something like `import logging;logging.basicConfig()`. That will create a handler for the root logger and should make the apscheduler happy.

Comment: Thank u! Your suggests fixed my problem and From the log file,I found that 'import os path = os.path.dirname(\_\_file\_\_)' python code made the bug. results showed "global "\_\_file\_\_"is not defined ", after I coded it like "path = 'F:\Python_Test' ", everthing is ok. So here what's wrong with "\_\_file\_\_"?

Comment: I don't have a good explanation for that unless you are typing it into the interpreter (that is, just running python and typing it in). Normally, \_\_file\_\_ is the current module's relative file name but there is no 'current module' for the interpreter and \_\_file\_\_ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

apscheduler is using the python [logging module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) which needs to be initialized. Logging is a bit complicated (see the link) but the minimum is to:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
```

basicConfig supports some common logging features but its worth figuring out some of the more sophisticated uses for the logger.