# Schedule Job with APScheduler Version 3

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am trying to schedule a job in python using the APScheduler package. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15090478) looked great, but it's snytax is out of date. I went to [user guide](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide.html) for the current version 3, but I cannot find a basic example where I can pass a `datetime` object to the scheduler like in the linked answer.

```
from datetime import date
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler as Scheduler
from datetime import datetime

# Start the scheduler
sched = Scheduler()
sched.start()

# Define the function that is to be executed
def my_job(text):
    print text

#Schedule job
job = sched.add_job(my_job, next_run_time = datetime(2015, 5, 11, 1, 05, 5), args = ['Hello World!'])
```

This yields the error: `No handlers could be found for logger "apscheduler.executors.default"`.

Comment: The code above worked for me... Looks like the error you get is related to logging module... see this answer and question http://stackoverflow.com/a/17551794/1478277

Comment: How about this? https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/triggers/date.html#module-apscheduler.triggers.date

Comment: Note also that with a script like this, your main thread will end as soon as you've scheduled that job, thus terminating the process.

Comment: @AlexGrönholm So if I added an infinite loop at the end of the script to keep it open the job would excecute at the specified time? What's the alternative?

Comment: Use BlockingScheduler. That's the very purpose it was made for.